# Simultaneus threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Ok. Maybe you get mad at me for not showing what I've tried. But I'm really confused with threads. What would be the simpliest possible way to run three threads simultaneously and after they all finished run a forth one? This would run inside a wx application so I want a way that would not lock up my program.

Edit: Well, the forth don't need to be a thread, but it is a method that need to be run when all off the threads are finished

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the basic idea would be something like this:

```
from threading import Thread

threads = [Thread(target=f1), Thread(target=f2), Thread(target=f3)]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

# Wait for all of them
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

# Do stuff afterwards
```

Note that threads can't do computation in parallel, because of the GIL, so you might need to use multiprocessing. But if they're waiting for a database or a network service, they will work as you expect.

Comment: That was really the best sample out there I've seen. Most of them is over complex and you really got what I was asking for in my question.